Why does the GeoJSON format expect coordinates in an array rather than an object with keys?
Take the following example from their home page:
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [125.6, 10.1]
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": "Dinagat Islands"
  }
}

The coordinates field expects longitude and latitude in the first and second indexes respectively of this array. This is confusing to me for the following reasons:

Longitude and latitude are not the same thing. Representing them in the same list seems illogical from a purely programming perspective however I understand that a list looks like traditional coordinates.
Human error is more likely with index-based variables in a list rather than accessing them through clearly labelled keys in an object. In fact, after briefly helping someone who is working with Leaflet, ArcGIS and GeoJSON, this exact thing happened. He accidentally swapped round the indexes for accessing longitude and latitude. Furthermore, one of the libraries expected the longitude and latitude to be the opposite way round, leading to further confusion. Even if the keys were differently arranged in an object, this same issue would not occur (unless you accessed the keys via indexes which is possible in some languages I suppose; but this is a bad practice that is generally avoided).
Regarding performance, in most contexts I expect GeoJSON to be processed in JavaScript via mapping libraries and the likes. Quickly looking at JavaScript arrays and objects, I can find both people claiming it is faster and slower, but either way, the performance difference seems to be not great enough to justify sacrificing semantics.

Is there any reason why this decision was made? What is the advantage of storing them in a list?

Specifications can be found here: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946


Shorter: "coordinates": [125.6, 10.1, 30.0] vs "coordinates": { "longitude": 125.6, "latitude": 10.1, "elevation": 30.0 }. Faster (not much but still) coordinates[0] is faster than coordinates.longitude. Convention: a lot of other languages are used to create and access coordinates and an array might be simple in those languages

@mplungjan I considered also the 'shorter' argument, but this only amounts to making the file size smaller. If this really was a goal, then simply store the data in csv and forget about a whole convention with long key names (see properties for example). The performance is questionable. Some benchmarks even claim it to be the other way round so this is also not a reason.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946#section-3.1.1

I've used geo libraries that use object notation using property names longitude/latitude, and Longitude/Latitude, and long/lat, and lon/lat, and x/y etc

@mplungjan There is no rationale in the documentation (I linked in my question and already had a look), simply a convention. They don't give a reason for WHY it is like that, simply that that is how it is, and it must be followed (because otherwise your program is not going to work). It is the WHY that interests me since it strikes me as a poor decision but indeed this is bordering the realm of opinions rather than facts, although I do believe a clear rationale should be available.

We were 3 that made that decision. I made my comment after voting to close - but by all means, I am voting to re-open

@mplungjan Thanks, sorry I did not mean it harshly, I just would love to get a reason for this decision for the standard to represent like that and thus far I can find nothing on this and was hoping somebody with more experience knew why. Thanks for reopening.

Actually I tried to find an actual documented reason and could not find it in the documentation or elsewhere other than "because that is what we use", hence it would become an opinion.

No problem, there are two votes to reopen, so let's see

You could ask here: https://mailarchive.ietf.org/arch/browse/geojson/?q=draft-butler-geojson

@mplungjan Bedankt, I will look there!
